# Angular bootstrap link to tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, tabs

I'm using Angular Bootstrap to display four tabs.  I'd like to update my (internal) URL every time the user selects a different tab, and have those links take the user to that tab.  I assume this is straightforward, but I'm failing to figure out how to do it.

Each tab is a directive.  Here's the html:

```
<div>
    <tabset>
        <tab heading = "Users"><back-admin-users></back-admin-users></tab>
        <tab heading = "Pending Purchases"><back-admin-pending></back-admin-pending></tab>
        <tab heading = "Store Settings"><back-admin-settings></back-admin-settings></tab>
        <tab heading = "Store Items"><back-admin-store></back-admin-store></tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to update my (internal) URL every time the user selects a different tab, and have those links take the user to that tab

I'm not sure to understand what do you mean by "update my (internal) URL"

If you mean that you want to add the tab selected as query string, it's pretty easy.
You create a function that you add to the scope, after that you bind this function to each tab by giving a different parameter, and the function update the url with the method "search" from $location service.

Example:

```
$scope.updateUrlWithTab = function(tabId){ // in your controller
    $location.search({tab: tabId);
};


<!-- in your view -->
<tab heading = "Users" ng-click="updateUrlWithTab(0)">your directive</tab>
<tab heading = "Pending Purchases" ng-click="updateUrlWithTab(1)">your directive</tab>
<tab heading = "Store Settings" ng-click="updateUrlWithTab(2)">your directive</tab>
<tab heading = "Store Items" ng-click="updateUrlWithTab(3)">your directive</tab>
```

If you click on "Users" you'll see your url become: yourUrl?tab=0

Otherwise, if you want to redirect to another page, same thing except that you use $location to redirect with "path" method

Example:

```
    var TAB = { // in a service
         Users: 0,
         PendingPurchases: 1,
         StoreSettings: 2,
         StoreItems: 3
    };

    $scope.updateUrlWithTab = function(tabId){ // in your controller
        switch(tabid){
           case YourService.TAB.Users:
               $location.path('#/Users');
               break;
           case YourService.TAB.PendingPurchases:
               $location.path('#/PendingPurchases');
               break;
           case YourService.TAB.StoreSettings:
               $location.path('#/StoreSettings');
               break;
           case YourService.TAB.StoreItems:
               $location.path('#/StoreItems');
               break;
        }
};
```

If you click on "Users" you'll see your url become: yourUrl/#/Users

Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

If the answer does not fit you, please give us more information, maybe a practical example that we can have a better understanding of your problem.